# Подключение к двум базам данным mysql node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

Есть необходимость подключаться к двум базам данных. Однако я хочу сделать что бы одно подключение было в одном файле, а работа с другой бд в другом файле и при запуске приложения сразу конектились 2 дб. Каким образом мне настроить это?

файл `moodleDb`:

```
const express = require("express")
const mysql = require("mysql")
const cors = require("cors")
const app = express();

const moodleDB = mysql.createConnection({
    user: "test",
    host: "test",
    password: "test",
    database: "test",
})

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
app.get("", (req, res) => {
    res.json("this is moodle db")
})


app.listen(8081, () => {
    console.log("Server moodle is running at 8081");
  });
```

файл `index.js`:

```
const express = require("express")
const mysql = require("mysql")
const cors = require("cors")
const app = express();

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    user: "root",
    host: "localhost",
    password: "",
    database: "edufinance",
})

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

app.get("", (req, res) => {
    res.json("this is my db")
})

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("was connected")
})
```

файл    `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "concurrently \"nodemon moodleDb.js\" \"nodemon index.js\""
    
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? Создаёте два соединения и работаете. В одном файле с одним, в другом с другим)

Comment: @AlexanderChernin сейчас я могу запустить только один сервер одновременно. другой же почему то хочет использовать порт 8080, хотя я указал 8081

Comment: Это другой вопрос. Как запустить СУБД на другом порту